# Use count(decode...) across multiple tables

Tags: oracle, count, decode

I have three 3 tables (having the same key) in the following structure:

**Input Table t1:**

```
file_in| f_in_state|
--------------------   
F01    | 1         |
F02    | 2         |
F21    | 1         |
F41    | 2         |
```

**Input Table t2:**

```
line_in| file_in| l_in_state |     
-----------------------------
L001   | F01     | 1         |
L002   | F01     | 2         |
L003   | F01     | 2         |
L004   | F01     | 2         |
L005   | F21     | 1         |
L006   | F21     | 1         |
L007   | F21     | 1         |
L008   | F21     | 1         |
```

**Input Table t3:**

```
line_out|line_in| file_in| l_out_state|     
---------------------------------------
D001    |L001    | F01    | 1          |
D002    |L002    | F01    | 1          |
D003    |L003    | F01    | 1          |
```

and I need to count the number of occurrences of the columns refering to the different states across my three tables for each ***"file in id"*** and then combine them to get an output like this:

```
file_in_id|file_in_state| A | B | C | D | E |
---------------------------------------------
F01       | 1           | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
F02       | 2           | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
F21       | 1           | 1 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
F41       | 2           | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
```

with:

- A refers to the number of input lines (*"line_in"*) having the state = '1'
- B refers to the number of input lines (*"line_in"*) having the state = '2'
- C refers to the number of input lines (*"line_in"*) having the state = '3' (in my case, there is no line with this state, but it is possible to happen)
- D refers to the number of output lines (*"line_out"*) having the state = '1'
- E refers to the number of output lines (*"line_out"*) having the state = '2'

So, I tried to use the decode function in my query but I didn't get the wished result.

```
SELECT
    t1.file_in AS file_in_id,    
    t1.f_in_state AS file_in_state,
    COUNT(DECODE(t2.f_in_state, '1', 1, null)) AS A,
    COUNT(DECODE(t2.f_in_state, '2', 1, null)) AS B,
    COUNT(DECODE(t2.f_in_state, '3', 1, null)) AS C,
   COUNT(DECODE(t3.f_out_state, '1', 1, null)) AS D,
   COUNT(DECODE(t3.f_out_state, '2', 1, null)) AS E
FROM table1 t1,
table2 t2,
table3 t3
WHERE t1.file_in = t2.file_in (+)
AND t2.file_in = t3.file_in (+)
GROUP BY t1.file_in, t1.f_in_state
ORDER BY t1.file_in
```

But, this is what I get :

```
file_in_id|file_in_state|A |B |C |D |E |
----------------------------------------
F01       |1            |1 |3 |9 |0 |12|
F02       |2            |2 |0 |0 |0 |0 |
F21       |1            |1 |4 |0 |0 |0 |
F41       |2            |2 |0 |0 |0 |0 |
```

Could somebody tells me what is wrong with this query and how can I fix it to get what I would like to have as a result.

It's very important, this is how the input table 3 should be :

**Input Table t3:**

```
line_out|*file_out*| file_in| l_out_state|     
---------------------------------------
D001    |W01    | F01    | 1          |
D002    |W01    | F01    | 1          |
D003    |W01    | F01    | 1          |
```

Comment: Can you rewrite the query in your question using explicit modern joins?  The `(+)` notation makes it harder to understand what you are doing.

Comment: + so does using decode() instead of much simpler SQL standard case expressions...

Comment: SELECT
    t1.file_in AS file_in_id,    
    t1.f_in_state AS file_in_state,
    COUNT(DECODE(t2.f_in_state, '1', 1, null)) AS A,
    COUNT(DECODE(t2.f_in_state, '2', 1, null)) AS B,
    COUNT(DECODE(t2.f_in_state, '3', 1, null)) AS C,
   COUNT(DECODE(t3.f_out_state, '1', 1, null)) AS D,
   COUNT(DECODE(t3.f_out_state, '2', 1, null)) AS E
FROM table1 t1 
left join table2 t2
on t1.file_in = t2.file_in
left join table3 t3
on t2.file_in = t3.file_in
GROUP BY t1.file_in, t1.f_in_state
ORDER BY t1.file_in

Comment: don't use comments for code, you are better off editing your question for such things, but now there are answers anyway. You will find that for any questions here you will want you to use ANSI standard join syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This query gives desired result:

```
select file_in, f_in_state,
       count(case l_in_state  when '1' then 1 end) a,
       count(case l_in_state  when '2' then 1 end) b,
       count(case l_in_state  when '3' then 1 end) c,
       count(case l_out_state when '1' then 1 end) d,
       count(case l_out_state when '2' then 1 end) e
  from t1 
  left join t2 using (file_in)
  left join t3 using (file_in, line_in)
  group by file_in, f_in_state
  order by file_in
```

You could also use `pivot` if you have Oracle 11g or above.

Test:

```
with t1(file_in, f_in_state) as (
    select 'F01', '1' from dual union all
    select 'F02', '2' from dual union all
    select 'F21', '1' from dual union all
    select 'F41', '2' from dual ),
t2(line_in, file_in, l_in_state) as (
    select 'L001', 'F01', '1' from dual union all
    select 'L002', 'F01', '2' from dual union all
    select 'L003', 'F01', '2' from dual union all
    select 'L004', 'F01', '2' from dual union all
    select 'L005', 'F21', '1' from dual union all
    select 'L006', 'F21', '1' from dual union all
    select 'L007', 'F21', '1' from dual union all
    select 'L008', 'F21', '1' from dual ), 
t3(line_out, line_in, file_in, l_out_state) as (
    select 'D001', 'L001', 'F01', '1' from dual union all
    select 'D002', 'L002', 'F01', '1' from dual union all
    select 'D003', 'L003', 'F01', '1' from dual )
select file_in, f_in_state,
       count(case l_in_state  when '1' then 1 end) a,
       count(case l_in_state  when '2' then 1 end) b,
       count(case l_in_state  when '3' then 1 end) c,
       count(case l_out_state when '1' then 1 end) d,
       count(case l_out_state when '2' then 1 end) e
  from t1 
  left join t2 using (file_in)
  left join t3 using (file_in, line_in)
  group by file_in, f_in_state
  order by file_in
```

Output:

```
FILE_IN F_IN_STATE          A          B          C          D          E
------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
F01     1                   1          3          0          3          0
F02     2                   0          0          0          0          0
F21     1                   4          0          0          0          0
F41     2                   0          0          0          0          0
```

Comment: I think that the pivot isn't helpful for me because I don't know the tables contents when running my query.

Comment: I made a mistake with the 3rd table and I think it could be a game-changer. 
  Actually, the 2nd column of table3 sould be **"file_out"** instead of "*LINE_IN*".
  In this way, I think it won't be possible to make the following join **(left join t3 using (file_in, line_in))**
  I am sorry to tell you this now.

Answer (score 0):

Variant with SUM

```
Select a.file_in, a.f_in_state,
Sum(Case When b.l_in_state=1 Then 1 Else 0 End) A,
Sum(Case When b.l_in_state=2 Then 1 Else 0 End) B,
Sum(Case When b.l_in_state=3 Then 1 Else 0 End) C,
Sum(Case When c.l_out_state=1 Then 1 Else 0 End) D,
Sum(Case When c.l_out_state=2 Then 1 Else 0 End) E
From T1 a
Left join T2 b on a.file_in=b.file_in
Left join T3 c on a.file_in=c.file_in and b.line_in=c.line_in
GROUP BY a.file_in, a.f_in_state
ORDER BY a.file_in
```